# Using POST from a function

Tags: javascript, php, function, post

I have a PHP script where I need to go to one of three different URL's based off a radio button selection, but I must send the variables via POST, as one URL is a third party page (not shown) and I cannot change it.

I have a function that determines the value of the radio button and is to direct the script, but I have found no way to control switching from GET to POST.

** Maybe there is a better way than using function that I am unaware of?

FYI-I have tried numerous button options, including button instead of input; what is shown below is simply the state of my latest.

```
<tr> 
  <th Align=Left vAlign=top rowSpan=6> <?=$THFont?> Payment Type</font></th>
  <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CK ID=Check Checked>
       <Label for=Check> Check</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CS ID=Cash>
       <Label for=Cash> Cash</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CH ID=Charge>
       <Label for=Charge> Charge to Broker AR Account</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type=text name=PayNote id=PayNote placeholder='Payment Note (for 3 payment types above)' maxlength=30 size=35></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CC ID=Credit>
       <Label for=Credit> Credit Card  &nbsp;<i>(Visa, Master Card, American Express, Discover)</i></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=NP ID=NoPay> 
       <Label for=NoPay> Reserve Without Payment</label></td>
</tr>


<input type="button" class="buttonProcess" value="Process" onclick="processPayment('<?=$EvntCode?>','<?=$SessionID?>','<?=$MbrID?>');">


  function processPayment(EvntCode,SessionID,MbrID) {
    var PayType = $("input:radio[name='PayType']:checked").val();
    var PayNote = document.getElementById('PayNote').value;
    if (PayType == "CK" || PayType == "CS" || PayType == "CH") {
      var url = "/apps/php/PayCashStaff_Process.php?EvntCode="+EvntCode+"&SessionID="+SessionID+"&MbrID="+MbrID+"&PayType="+PayType+"&PayNote="+PayNote;
      processPay = window.location.href=url;
    }
    if (PayType == "CC") {
      var url = "/apps/php/PayCCStaff_Home.php?EvntCode="+EvntCode+"&SessionID="+SessionID+"&MbrID="+MbrID;
      processCCPay = window.location.href=url;
    }
    if (PayType == "NP") {
      var url = "/apps/php/ConfirmReservation_Process.php?EvntCode="+EvntCode+"&SessionID="+SessionID+"&MbrID="+MbrID;
      confResWindow = window.location=(url);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're changing the browser url as part of the clicking of a button.  That's always going to be a GET.  If you want it to be a POST, and you want the page to transfer to that page as a result, you need to submit a form.

Comment: Unless there is a way that I am unaware of, a form will not allow me to evaluate the selections to determine what URL to direct to.  With form you are given "action", which is to be a URL, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the form first, then submit it (Not using AJAX). Form will be submitted and user will be taken to destination:

```js
function processPayment(EvntCode, SessionID, MbrID) {
  var PayType = $("input:radio[name='PayType']:checked").val();
  var PayNote = document.getElementById('PayNote').value;
  if (PayType == "CK" || PayType == "CS" || PayType == "CH") {
    var url = "/apps/php/PayCashStaff_Process.php?EvntCode=" + EvntCode + "&SessionID=" + SessionID + "&MbrID=" + MbrID + "&PayType=" + PayType + "&PayNote=" + PayNote;
    processPay = window.location.href = url;
  }
  if (PayType == "CC") {
    var url = "/apps/php/PayCCStaff_Home.php?EvntCode=" + EvntCode + "&SessionID=" + SessionID + "&MbrID=" + MbrID;
    processCCPay = window.location.href = url;
  }
  if (PayType == "NP2") {
    var url = "/apps/php/ConfirmReservation_Process.php?EvntCode=" + EvntCode + "&SessionID=" + SessionID + "&MbrID=" + MbrID;
    confResWindow = window.location = (url);
  }

  if (PayType == "NP") {
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('method', "post");
    f.setAttribute('action', "https://postman-echo.com/post");
    f.setAttribute('id', "postform");

    var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, hidden
    i.setAttribute('type', "hidden");
    i.setAttribute('name', "EvntCode");
    i.setAttribute('value', EvntCode);
    f.appendChild(i);

    i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, hidden
    i.setAttribute('type', "hidden");
    i.setAttribute('name', "SessionID");
    i.setAttribute('value', SessionID);
    f.appendChild(i);

    i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, hidden
    i.setAttribute('type', "hidden");
    i.setAttribute('name', "MbrID");
    i.setAttribute('value', MbrID);
    f.appendChild(i);

    document.body.appendChild(f);

    f.submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left vAlign=top rowSpan=6>
      <?=$THFont?> Payment Type</font>
    </th>
    <td>
      <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CK ID=Check Checked>
      <Label for=Check> Check</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CS ID=Cash>
      <Label for=Cash> Cash</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CH ID=Charge>
      <Label for=Charge> Charge to Broker AR Account</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type=text name=PayNote id=PayNote placeholder='Payment Note (for 3 payment types above)' maxlength=30 size=35></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CC ID=Credit>
      <Label for=Credit> Credit Card  &nbsp;<i>(Visa, Master Card, American Express, Discover)</i></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=NP ID=NoPay>
      <Label for=NoPay> Reserve Without Payment</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="buttonProcess" value="Process" onclick="processPayment('fooEvent','fooSess','fooMbr');">
```

Note: A nice form construction function could be made but you get the idea.

Comment: I am a rookie to javascript, the code you added that starts with, if (PayType == "TypeToPost"){, with the setAttribute, etc. is new to me.  At any rate, I copied all the code you provided and when I run it, I am asked for an authorized sign in to our system, I thought that odd, but tried signing in and fail it fails.

Comment: @BrianMiller Just replace `TypeToPost` with whatever you intended for it to be (CK, CC, etc). I wasn't sure which condition/link you wanted to POST to rather than GET.

Comment: I am able to get the code to process, but my variables are blank in the receiving script, so I assume I am missing a piece.

I added this code after yours:

            var url = "/apps/php/ConfirmReservation_Process.php";
            confResWindow = window.location=(url);

Comment: One other note, my form looks like this:

<form method=POST id=postform>

<input type="button" class="buttonProcess" value="Process" onclick="processPayment('<?=$EvntCode?>','<?=$SessionID?>','<?=$MbrID?>');">

</form>

I know the fields have value in the function because I put an alert to test the value.

Comment: @BrianMiller Fixed it. I had forgot to append the form to body. You will have to add your inline PHP back to the HTML. `NP` condition was used for example purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the information and sticking with me xendi!  I now have this working.  Anyone else following this, note that the line xendi has, 
    f.setAttribute('action', "https://postman-echo.com/post");, here you put your link to where you want to go.

Comment: @BrianMiller np

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function processPayment2(EvntCode,SessionID,MbrID) {
    var PayType = $("input:radio[name='PayType']:checked").val();
    var PayNote = document.getElementById('PayNote').value;
    if (PayType == "NP") {
      var f = document.createElement("form");
      f.setAttribute('method',"POST");
      f.setAttribute('action',"https://xxxxxxx.xxxx.com/apps/php/member/Event/ConfirmReservation_Process.php");
      f.setAttribute('id',"postform");

      var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, hidden
      i.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
      i.setAttribute('name',"EvntCode");
      i.setAttribute('value', EvntCode);
      f.appendChild(i);

      i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, hidden
      i.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
      i.setAttribute('name',"SessionID");
      i.setAttribute('value', SessionID);
      f.appendChild(i);

      i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, hidden
      i.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
      i.setAttribute('name',"MbrID");
      i.setAttribute('value', MbrID);
      f.appendChild(i);

      document.body.appendChild(f);

      f.submit();
    }
  }
</script>


<table cellSpacing=5>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Event Code: </font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont?> <?=$EvntCode?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Session:</font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont?> <?=$SessionID?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Title:</font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont?> <?=trim($event_row["TITLE"])?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Name:</font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont>> <?=trim($MbrMst02_MNAME)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Email:</font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont?> <?=trim($MbrMst02_MBWADR)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Amount:</font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont?> <?=money_format('%(#10n', $zAmount)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left> <?=$THFont?> Transaction Number:</font></th>
    <td> <?=$TDFont?> <?=$zTrnID?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colSpan=2><hr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th Align=Left vAlign=top rowSpan=6> <?=$THFont?> Payment Type</font></th> 
    <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CK ID=Check Checked>
         <Label for=Check> Check</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CS ID=Cash>
         <Label for=Cash> Cash</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CH ID=Charge>
         <Label for=Charge> Charge to Broker AR Account</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type=text name=PayNote id=PayNote placeholder='Payment Note (for 3 payment types above)' maxlength=30 size=35></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=CC ID=Credit> 
         <Label for=Credit> Credit Card  &nbsp;<i>(Visa, Master Card, American Express, Discover)</i></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <Input Name=PayType Type=Radio Value=NP ID=NoPay>
         <Label for=NoPay> Reserve Without Payment</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" class="buttonProcess" value="Process" onclick="processPayment2('<?=$EvntCode?>','<?=$SessionID?>','<?=$MbrID?>');">
```

[View screen snippet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFrFp.png)

Comment: You don't have to do this. You can just edit my answer. It's more proper to do it that way on this site.